# Suphp connection reset by peer in error logs

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, socket, suphp, zend

In my Linux server's logs I have this record nearly every 5 minutes. I couldn't find the reason for two weeks and I would be very happy if you can recommend me a way to diagnose the problem.

It is inside error_log file. I use php 5.3.8 and litespeed 5.5.

```
2012-09-03 16:01:28.399 [INFO]
[95.7.223.91:63814-0#APVH_example.com]
connection to [/tmp/lshttpd/
APVH_example.com_Suphp.sock.
781] on request #151, confirmed, 0,
associated process: 845244, running: 0, error: Connection reset by peer!
```

Comment: What makes you think there's a problem?

Comment: I get this error in day hours. Especially in these hours. When I have difficulties entering my site, because site opens very late. I check error log and find this.

Comment: I can reach my homepage nearly in 30 seconds,sometimes more.

Comment: So, to clarify, your problem is that sometimes when you try to reach your site, it doesn't respond for awhile, but after 30 seconds or so, you get the page normally?

Comment: yes david when I wait for 20-40 seconds I get my page normally. This doesn't happen in night or mornings.